# Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` - Spring boot, elasticseach, jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jackson

I'm using `Spring-boot 2.0.0.M7` and `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` and `elasticsearch 5` and I'm getting an error by deserializing a `LocalDate` field.

My Document looks like that:

```
@Document(indexName= "myIndex", type = "cluster")
public class Cluster {

    @Id
    @Field
    private Long id;
    @Field
    private String name;
    @Field
    private ClusterUrl clusterUrl;
    @Field
    private ClusterVisible clusterVisible;
}
```

Where ClusterVisible is a child object which holds the `LocalDates`:

```
public class ClusterVisible {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    private LocalDate start;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    private LocalDate end;
}
```

So I just make a query for one cluster Id and I get this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"id":12345,"name":"Cluster name ","clusterName":{"de":"Cluster de","it":null,"fr":null},"clusterUrl":{"de":"/url/results","it":null,"fr":null},"clusterVisible":{"start":{"year":2017,"month":"OCTOBER","dayOfMonth":9,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","era":"CE","dayOfYear":282,"leapYear":false,"mo"[truncated 252 chars]; line: 1, column: 388] (through reference chain: com.example.elasticsearch5.es.cluster.model.Cluster["clusterVisible"]->com.example.elasticsearch5.es.cluster.model.ClusterVisible["start"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1451)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1027)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1290)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2992)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.DefaultEntityMapper.mapToObject(DefaultEntityMapper.java:65)
```

I already know that I need to add some jackson dependencies for the `java.time api` so I added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But this does not help for now. I also checked the entry in the index by making a query using kibana. The result of the query is:

```
...
"clusterVisible": {
    "start": {
      "year": 2017,
      "month": "OCTOBER",
      "dayOfMonth": 25,
      "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
      "era": "CE",
      "dayOfYear": 298,
      "leapYear": false,
      "monthValue": 10,
      "chronology": {
        "id": "ISO",
        "calendarType": "iso8601"
      }
    },
    "end": {
      "year": 3000,
      "month": "JANUARY",
      "dayOfMonth": 1,
      "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
      "era": "CE",
      "dayOfYear": 1,
      "leapYear": false,
      "monthValue": 1,
      "chronology": {
        "id": "ISO",
        "calendarType": "iso8601"
      }
    }
}
```

What do I miss for fixing this error?

Addition: The exact error occours at `mapper.mapToObject`. So I created a `new DefaultEntityMapper();` some lines before. Could that be the issue?

```
@Override
public Page<Cluster> findClustersAndScoreByText(String text) {
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(text).lenient(true).defaultOperator(Operator.OR)
                    .field("name")
                    .field("svno"));

    NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(queryBuilder)
            .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 100)).build();

    DefaultEntityMapper mapper = new DefaultEntityMapper();
    ResultsExtractor<Page<Cluster>> rs = new ResultsExtractor<Page<Cluster>>() {

        @Override
        public Page<Cluster> extract(SearchResponse response) {
            ArrayList<Cluster> hotels = new ArrayList<>();
            SearchHit[] hits = response.getHits().getHits();
            for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
                try {
                    Cluster cluster = mapper.mapToObject(hit.getSourceAsString(), Cluster.class);
                    cluster.setScore(hit.getScore());
                    hotels.add(cluster);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return new PageImpl<>(hotels, PageRequest.of(0, 100), response.getHits().getTotalHits());
        }
    };

    return elasticsearchTemplate.query(nativeSearchQuery, rs);
}
```

Comment: Your start and end data are objects... Why would  `pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy"`  work?

Comment: @cricket_007 should be ok for deserializing to the frontend. But I removed it and there is no change.

Comment: The error is telling you that no default constructor exists for a localdatetime and its an immutable class, so it can't just call `setters` for each field in the json. Why don't you write your own class for that object?

Comment: @cricket_007 if the config does not work I need to write my own class. I autowired the jackson object mapper instead using a new one, I get another exception for localdate: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: Expected array or string.` any idea?

Comment: `"start": {` is an object, as the error says. `JsonFormat.Shape.STRING` is trying to *parse a string*, which you don't have

Answer (score 34):

add below annotation over the field LocalDate

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate start;
```

Comment: this solution would not work if these are auto-generated stubs. Answer by @evdelacruz is more valid

Comment: it's not enough

Answer (score 8):

**Date/time format**, according to ISO 8601 is **"YYYY-MM-DD"**, so your pattern should be:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

**Instead of:**

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
```

Another way is adding in your **application.yml**

```
spring:
    jackson:
        serialization:
            WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
```

Or disable this feature directly in your object mapper:

```
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
```

Comment: How can I disable the serialization for one request and not all of them?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa, the ObjectMapper is a bean that is built within the ApplicationContext to be injected as needed. I'm afraid u will need to use Jackson custom annotations to achieve that.
Another possibility is to treat the field as a String within the DTO/VO/TO and then parse it as desired within that specific scenario/request.

Answer (score 7):

need to install JsonFormat JsonDeserialize JsonSerialize

```
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @PastOrPresent(message = "must be past time or present")
    @Column(name = "date_of_birth", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DATE")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `@JsonFormat`. All you need is `DateFormat.date` param in annotation (kotlin):

```kotlin
@Field(type = Date, format = date)
val created: LocalDate = now()
```

Elasticsearch doesn't use Jackson but instead a [MappingElasticsearchConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping).

Date will be saved in elastic in format: `2020-01-02`, mapping will be:

```json
 "created" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "date"
        }
```

---